# CONCATENAR RESULTAS DE UMA UNICA COLUNA sql SERVER

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

TENHO O SEGUINTE SELECT

```
select NUMERO_ASSEMBLEIA
  from COBRANCAS 
  where 1=1
    and CODIGO_GRUPO = 443
    and CODIGO_COTA = 11
    and VERSAO = 0 
    and ORIGEM_LANCAMENTO is null
```

E ELE ME RETORNAR ESSA

NUMERO_ASSEMBLEIA

53

55

56

54

GOSTARIA DE SABER SE TEM ALGUMA FORMA DE EU FAZER ELE ME RETORNAR ESTES VALORES CONCATENANDO TODOS ELES ?

Comment: se estiver usando sql server 2017+ pode usar a função `STRING_AGG`: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15]

Comment: EU USO SQL 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma alternativa para testes utilizando XML para concatenar os valores (supondo que o tipo de dados seja numérico (Cast)):

```
select
    stuff
        ((select ', ' + cast(NUMERO_ASSEMBLEIA as varchar(10))
          from COBRANCAS 
          where 1=1
            and CODIGO_GRUPO = 443
            and CODIGO_COTA = 11
            and VERSAO = 0 
            and ORIGEM_LANCAMENTO is null
          for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 
         1, 
         2, 
         '')
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é isso que você deseja, mas a única maneira que eu conheço é esta.

```
declare @variavel varchar(1000)
set @variavel = ''
select @variavel = @variavel + NUMERO_ASSEMBLEIA
  from COBRANCAS 
  where 1=1
    and CODIGO_GRUPO = 443
    and CODIGO_COTA = 11
    and VERSAO = 0 
    and ORIGEM_LANCAMENTO is null

print @variavel
```

Comment: muito obrigado pessoal, pelas resposta eu consegui utilizando o XML path conforme o colega da primeira resposta mencionou